# google apps script - web app doesn't seem to do anything . .

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a Java developer but I did a small site for a non-profit group using Google Sites.  I have a form I'd like to be somewhat dynamic and Google Apps Script seemed to be a viable option.  As frequently happens when one is learning a new technology, I copied and pasted the code below from a tutorial/documentation.  I then published it, and inserted the script widget into a page on the site and saved the page.  When I reload the page, the "place holder" for the widget is there, but nothing happens - no buttons, no panel, nothing.  Same results when I run it from the script editor.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to get the UI to render at all.  A little direction would be greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance!

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log("Executing the doGet() method . . .");

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var aPanelRoot = app.createVerticalPanel();

  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  aPanelRoot.add(button);

  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.');
  label.setId('statusLabel');
  aPanelRoot.add(label);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  handler.addCallbackElement(label);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  aPanelRoot.setVisible(true);
  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setVisible(true);

  //app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you simply forgot to add `aPanelRoot` to the app in the `doGet()` function

```
app.add(aPanelRoot)
```

also : by default all widgets are visibles so you can remove all the `setVisible(true)` statements as they are only necessary if you set them to `false` somewhere else...

And if I may add a last comment, it's generally a good idea to choose the parent widget as `callbackElement` so you don't risk to forget to add elements when you begin to have lots of them (all children are automatically included in the parent) .

Comment: Thanks for your help, Serge.  That (of course) was the issue.  I was so wrapped up in trying to deploy it right, I missed the obvious.  Understood re: setting object to visible - that was a reach (in frustration).  I understand your point re: callbackElement - thanks again!